How can i send data from react to flask?
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/check-password' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
I dont understand what is the problem
`from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app , origins="*")


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','OPTIONS'])
def hello_world():  # put application's code here
    return 'Hello World!'


def check_password_strength(password):
    if len(password) < 6:
        return 'Weak'
    elif any(char.isdigit() for char in password):
        return 'Medium'
    else:
        return 'Strong'


@app.route('/check-password', methods=['POST', 'OPTIONS'])
def check_password(password: str):
    strength = check_password_strength(password)
    response = jsonify({'strength': strength})
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
`

And a simple code in React that use axios to send a post with the password

Please edit your question and add your "simple code in React".
